# What is best Xcode version that works with the most existing devices

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the best Xcode version to use to compile an iOS app that will run on the greatest number of devices already out there?
iPhone iPod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use the latest stable version. 
As of today this would be Xcode 4.1 if you are on Lion and Xcode 4.0.2 if you are on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Here is a more specific question begging an answer:
If I use the LATEST IOS, can older devices, with the required hardware, still buy the app and run it okay?
Does Apple make it obvious to them to easily download iOS upgrade for the app?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the latest one. To date, 4.1